# vehicle's obstacle avoidance sensor

Tags: c, microcontroller, sensors, robotics

I'm new in robotics and I would like to make a vehicle in order to play with my 3 years-old son. I have a PIC 16F917 microcontroller and a Half H bridge L293DNE. What I've tried so far in order to make the vehicle move is s C code guided by the following link: http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.societyofrobots.com%2Fmember_tutorials%2Ffiles%2FLukas%2520PIC%2520Tutorial.doc&ei=8tWCT4GeNZD6sgaQmYzRBA&usg=AFQjCNFw6ZoQSyoKwRj3uPaLmchgBzGY4Q&sig2=tLQ7VN9IJen-TXCznu4jLA. So I was able to make the robot move forward, backward and turn left and right. What I want to do now is to find suitable sensors for obstacle avoidance. Since I have no previous experience could someone recommend the appropriate  compatible with the microcontroller sensors? If so, I would like to know in which pins of microcontroller I should connect the sensors and moreover the suitable programming order in C , for the sensors to interact with the microcontroller.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your Qn will receive proper guidance here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and not in SO

Comment: http://www.parallax.com/Store/Sensors/ObjectDetection/tabid/176/CategoryID/51/List/0/SortField/0/Level/a/ProductID/92/Default.aspx  and there are many other similar solutions, you can use infrared send out pulses and receive them perhaps you wont receive them unless there is an object reflecting them.  motion sensors can be used. http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/84

Comment: Please checkout and contribute to the new robotics stackexchange forum: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics

Answer (score 1):

The sparkfun link in a previous comment is a good place to get sensors.

Ultrasonic sensors are good for rough estimations of distance.  They have a wide beam, and the results are noisy.  Sharp IR sensors have a narrower beam and are a little more accurate.  And for very close range, (and very cheap), you can simply use an IR emitter and detector.  Typically, the IR is pulsed so that you can measure the difference between ambient IR lighting and when the pulse is on.  (Search for "infrared proximity detector with a 555 timer", or something along those lines).